# Rails beginner architecture - more than one model with file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, ruby-on-rails-5

I am just learning rails, i am struggling to work out the best way to structure my app.

I have two models

```
Jobs
Posts
```

These are separate parts of the app but each can have many files uploaded with each record

I was wondering the best way to structure this, do i ...

1 - Keep all files in one table.. Create a **Uploads** model then associate each type via a has_many :through (or polymorphic association)

2 - Use separate tables - Create **JobUploads** and **PostUploads** models (i don't envisage sharing of files between concerns)

I think either would work, my main confusion is the controllers/routes

Would i create new **UploadsController** or  **JobUploadsController** & **PostUploadsController** depending on the method i chose or would you add new actions to the existing Posts and Jobs Controller?

i guess an ideal route to upload an job image would be **/jobs/:job_id/files/new**, is this the correct way to do it?

If i make new controllers i'd end up with **/job_files/new** then i assume i'd have to pass the job object somehow.

Sorry if its a little obvious to some

Many thanks!

(ps using rails 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best shot is creating a polymorphic association, or as your said UploadsController . Lets say you are uploading images.

```
class UploadedImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, as: : imageable
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, as: : imageable
end
```

Remember to define in your `routes.rb`

```
concerns :imageable do
  resources :uploaded_images, shallow: true
end

resources :posts, concerns: [:imageable]
resources :jobs, concerns: [:imageable]
```

This will create routes likes -> /posts/:post_id/images,    /jobs/:job_id/images

Then you just need to get the type inside your UploadedImagesController. There you can load the imageable type and attach an image to it. An example controller would look like

```
class UploadedImagesController < ApplicationController

    prepend_before_filter :load_imageable,  only: :create

    def create
      @image = @imageable.images.create(image_params)
      render json: @image.as_json
    end

    def update
      @image = UploadedImage.find(params[:id])
      @image.update(image_params)
      render json: @image.as_json
    end

    def destroy
      @image = UploadedImage.find(params[:id])
      @image.destroy!
      render json: @image.as_json
    end

    private

    def load_imageable
      params.keys.select { |k| k =~ /([a-z_]*)_id/ }.first
      @imageable = $1.camelcase.constantize.find(params["#{$1}_id"])
    end

    def image_params
      params.require(:image).permit(:file, :caption)
    end
end
```

Using the polymorphic association will bring many advantages and allow for much code reuse, as you realize that many current and future models of your system will act as an imageable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best idea here is to decide on a gem for file upload. The most popular ones are **paperclip gem** or **carrierwave gem**. Than according to their documentation you can do the upload.

[//github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave](http:////github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

[//github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip](http:////github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

If using carrierwave for example you don't need to create a controller. You can create an uploader and mount it in your model...

Gems are the easiest way to do file uploads in rails.
You do not really need to create an upload controller. You can add a column to your posts, jobs and let the gem handle the upload. Detailed information is found in the links above

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The actual mechanics of uploading i am ok with (i think) looked at carrierwave, but will checkout paperclip also. It was more a hypothetical question on the structure of the whole thing. Thanks again.

Comment: carrierwave looks like it wants to store multiple uploads in a single field in the model